# VScode remote-containers (Running the contributed command: 'remote-containers.openFolder' failed.)

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-extensions, wsl-2

I'm a little new to this, but I'm trying to open up a container with an existing docker-compose file using the Remote-Containers extension in VSCode. Was able to do it earlier today but now I keep running into this error (error below and screenshot in link). Tried a few things like reinstalling remote-containers extension in VScode, reinstalling VSCode, restarting the computer, but I still seem to be getting this error.

['remote-containers.openFolder' failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osJhc.png)

*"Command 'Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container...' resulted in an error (Running the contributed command: 'remote-containers.openFolder' failed*

These commands seem to fail only when I try to put the directory I am in into the container. I don't seem to be having this issue with other directories.

I'm using WSL2: Ubuntu-20.04 to open up VSCode.

VSCode, Version: 1.59.0 (user setup)

Remote - Containers, Version: 0.191.0

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as making sure your container is already running in Docker in the background

I had the same issue when trying to rebuild and reopen a huge repo but realized I wasn't running my container already.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).